# How can I get the jQuery methos text() function to work in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am using jQuery Library to dynamically change my page.

But I am having an issue when using text() method. I get this error only in IE8 and below.

Unexpected call to method or property access.

Here is my code

```
$('.survey-navigator').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //console.log( $('#survey-optional-controls').val() );
    //return;
    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
    $(this).text('Processing...');
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'survey-previous'){
        $('#survey-nav-direction').val('previous');
    }
    $('#survey_form').submit();
});
```

IE 8 is complaining about the line `$(this).text('Processing...');`

I tried to changing the method `text()` to `html()` which gave me the same error.

Here is my HTML markup for the button

```
<div class="col-md-4 text-right">
<input class="btn btn-primary survey-navigator" type="submit" value="Next Page &#62;&#62;">
```

How can I get IE 8 to recognize that text method?

Comment: You're probably using jQuery 2, which dropped support for old IE, which IMO makes it rather pointless.

Comment: `input` doesn't have `text`. Use `$(this).val('Processing...');`

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan you are right. after using .val() it worked. I was just going to post that. thank you

Answer (score -2):

you can try html() instead of text(), but if your .survey-navigator is a form element, text() won't work, you need to use .val()